# Can't Get Microphone on Arch Linux to Work Using Pipewire(alsamixer shows that everything is on and good)

Tags: arch-linux, alsa, microphone, pipewire

For the past 5-6 hours I've been trying to get my microphone to work but I genuinely can't figure it out. Simply installed pipewire, pipewire-alsa, wireplumber, alsa-utils and made sure there were no conflicting pulseaudio packages. Sound from things like videos works perfect but the microphone won't work when I'm in calls or at all.

Here's my /etc/asound.conf:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw           
    card 1
}
```

This helped me switch to the right card and got the headphone audio working but the mic remains unfixed.

```
$ amixer sset Master unmute
$ amixer sset Speaker unmute
$ amixer sset Headphone unmute
```

^Both 'Master' and 'Headphone' return '[on]' and 100% percent but 'Speaker' returns 'unable to find simple control... which seems normal because I'm not using one.

```
$ arecord --duration=5 --format=dat test-mic.wav
$ aplay test-mic.wav
```

Returns a low, soft static back to me.

I've clicked through around a dozen posts and it seems that entering the correct code in /etc/asound.conf or switching to and unmuting the correct card in alsamixer has worked for most people. Scowered through arch pipewire wiki, alsa wiki, wireplumber wiki and genuinely can't find the solution. I hit 'f4' in alsamixer like it says in section 2.4 of the wiki, turned everything on and to max vol and the mic still won't work. I thought this seemed promising but the files don't exist(all the packages are 100% downloaded):

[image]

I'd truly appreciate any help. I'm more than certain I'm overlooking and probably over-complicating the problem. Just started using Arch, apologies for any annoying mistakes in the post, just trying to learn to rtfm and learn, thanks.